# MySQL regex looking for facebook links

Tags: mysql, regex, url

I saved several Facebook links in a table.

e.g.

(1) http ://www.facebook.com/page/AforApple

(2) https ://www.facebook.com/page/BforBanana

(3) http ://www.facebook.com/page/CforCat

I only want to focus the searching after the latest slash symbol. 
Search the result by ignoring the Facebook domain (http ://www.facebook.com/page/ or http s://www.facebook.com/page/)

For example,

- if I input the keyword 'Apple', then it returns (1)
- if I input the keyword 'for', then it returns (1) (2) (3)
- if I input the keyword 'cat', then it returns (3)
- if I input the keyword 'http', no results found.
- if I input the keyword 'www', no results found.
- if I input the keyword 'book', no results found.

I have read a post called ' [Mysql regex looking for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849249/mysql-regex-looking-for-links) ', but there is a little different with this case.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Which results do you want?  Also provide some results you do not want.

Comment: I don't want the result: if I inputted 'face' when searching, it displays all three records.

Comment: I only want to search the result with the latest section, i.e. 'AforApple' / 'BforBanana' / 'CforCat' these three chars, thanks.

Comment: Your question is beyond confusing.  These are regex strings and queries in your example, and then you keep saying "if I input" as if you have some application with variables.  Then your query brings back all the results it should and you say you don't want that?  Nobody can help you with this if you can't clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select * from table_name where column_name regexp '\/[^\/]*keyword[^\/]*$';
```

See [DEMO on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b6b5/10)

Answer (score 0):

In case there are some links in Facebook like

- http ://www.facebook.com/pages/FanPage/12345678901234
- http ://www.facebook.com/FanPage
- http ://www.facebook.com/pages/FanPage/12345678901234?fref=tck

I have enhanced the query little bit.

```
select * from table_name where column_name regexp '[^\/]*page[^.]*$';
```

And I can find all three results above.

Just for sharing, anyway thanks **karthik manchala** for help again!!!